# "Sought for" at the end of a sentence

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, poetry

Does anyone know if "sought for" can be used at the end of a clause, phrase, or sentence, even if "for" might be redundant? I'm not speaking of "sought for [something]", but "sought for" as an ending (with a period or comma only).

Comment: That was the goal sought for? No need for *for*, built into the word *sought*. If redundant, just don't. To seek is to look for, already.

Comment: Yes, agree. Certainly, in prose. However, the specific use is for poetry/song. Trying for meter, rhythm, and an ideal number of syllables. Also, for example, consider "fought for", where it make obvious sense. Also, I was wondering about historical usages, perhaps outdated uses.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U...consider doing a minimum of research as requested on the [Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)...that said, your Q  appears interesting.

Comment: It would help if you explained why you think it might *not* be acceptable at the end of a clause or sentence. I can think of plenty of examples that end with "for",  preceded by a past participle: sought, fought, claimed, spied, framed, died, came, lied, named, cried, famed, tried....

Comment: Responding to Chappo: I'm trying to find just one example where it is acceptable. I see you included "sought" in your list.

Comment: In many cases, *the noun for which we verbed* = *the noun we verbed for*. But for reasons that I and others have not been able to express, this equivalence breaks down in the case of *sought*.  Why? The question seems too subtle for ELL and should not be closed for “lack of research”, when none of us has been able to point to the area of research. Leave open.

Comment: "The noun for which we verbed = ..." Very helpful. Yes. Thank you for that.